# How do you use .replace with a 'long string' (""") in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a long string which opens and closes with 3 double quotes (""").
When I use the .replace function on it, it doesn't work (nor does it return an error or anything). It appears to run the code and then when I print the updated string, it hasn't actually changed.

```
surnames="""
Smith    
Jones    
Taylor
"""
```

*Say I wanted to replace the uppercase 'S' in 'Smith' with an 'A' for example:*

```
surnames.replace("S", "A")
```

It doesn't work! Is it even possible to do these operations on long strings in Python?

Comment: It does work, it just doesn't work _in place_. Try assigning the output of `surnames.replace("S", "A")` to a new variable.

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The way you write your string literal doesn't matter. A str is str, "long strings" is not a thing in Python.

Where your code goes wrong, is the fact that a str is *immutable* and that the `replace` method returns a new string with the result of the replace operation.  So you have to write:

```
surnames = surnames.replace("S", "A")
```

if you want to make surnames contain the new string.

Comment: Yeah got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The program:

```
s = "SMMMM" \
    "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"

print(s.replace("S", "A"))
print(s)
```

The Output:

```
AMMMMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
SMMMMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```